# Cannot access IP address on server after 3 days of waiting

Tags: ip

A client of mine who hosts their websites with Hurricane Electric added a dedicated IP address to 2 of their accounts, three days ago.

However, I am unable to work on their website as the dedicated IP address will not load anything for me; it just times out.  However, to make things worse, I have had friends around the country try to load the IP address in their browser and it loads just fine for them.  It would seem any computer or phone connected to my home network cannot access the dedicated IP addresses.

One of them is `http://65.49.51.227/`

Could someone please tell me what I can do to resolve this nightmare?  I am about to lose the job as it's been nearly 4 days and I can't even start my work yet!

Comment: Having the other IP address of the server (one that works) would be helpful for comparison.

Comment: @MichaelHampton hello sorry for the confusion.  I meant that I have 2 servers, each now has 1 IP each and not 2 IP's for 1 server

Comment: It sounds like your IP is being blocked.

Comment: Turns out my IP was blocked on the server, somehow wordpress had made several thousand requests from my IP in a short period so they IP blocked me....so the problem is resolved now, thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you run a traceroute.

```
$ traceroute 65.49.51.227
traceroute to 65.49.51.227 (65.49.51.227), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.25.50.1 (172.25.50.1)  0.364 ms  0.473 ms  0.609 ms
 2  172.25.49.1 (172.25.49.1)  3.722 ms  3.828 ms  4.962 ms
 3  73.195.236.1 (73.195.236.1)  33.326 ms  34.256 ms  34.357 ms
 4  te-4-4-ur01.manchester.nh.boston.comcast.net (68.87.156.25)  35.028 ms  35.562 ms  35.665 ms
 5  be-65-ar01.needham.ma.boston.comcast.net (68.85.69.165)  37.216 ms  38.148 ms  38.549 ms
 6  he-2-6-0-0-cr01.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.93.33)  46.651 ms  45.528 ms  44.266 ms
 7  he-0-13-0-0-pe03.111eighthave.ny.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.85.182)  41.303 ms  40.190 ms  40.961 ms
 8  66.110.96.137 (66.110.96.137)  41.660 ms 66.110.96.141 (66.110.96.141)  103.340 ms 66.110.96.133 (66.110.96.133)  198.579 ms
 9  63.243.128.121 (63.243.128.121)  200.059 ms  200.147 ms  200.685 ms
10  nyk-b5-link.telia.net (213.248.100.177)  199.866 ms  199.359 ms  199.231 ms
11  nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.135.18)  218.178 ms  217.146 ms  218.260 ms
12  sjo-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.130.129)  270.667 ms  275.737 ms  274.602 ms
13  hurricane-ic-138359-sjo-bb1.c.telia.net (213.248.67.106)  283.243 ms  281.890 ms  96.572 ms
14  10ge1-1.core1.fmt1.he.net (72.52.92.109)  126.793 ms  92.453 ms  96.489 ms
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  *^C
```

Hm, interesting. Maybe you have this firewalled.

How about ping?

```
$ ping 65.49.51.227
PING 65.49.51.227 (65.49.51.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 65.49.51.227: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=97.5 ms
64 bytes from 65.49.51.227: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=95.0 ms
^C
--- 65.49.51.227 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 95.052/96.318/97.584/1.266 ms
```

Works great. So your server is up and running.

But where is your service?

```
$ telnet 65.49.51.227 http
Trying 65.49.51.227...
Connected to 65.49.51.227.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 00:43:18 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Your web server seems up and running.

So, you should at least do these tests to try to determine where your connectivity is failing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with ping and tracert is that they are not service diagnostic tools. Ping and tracert are only good as general connectivity tests if you know that the target should respond. Can ping tell me why my web site isn't available? No it can't. My ISP, router or web server may block ICMP but happily serve HTTP. Tracert is a better tool for detecting general network routing issues but can't tell me much about why I can't get to a web site, again because ICMP may be blocked somewhere along the path.

Do ping and tracert have a place in your network toolkit? Yes. Can they both be a red herring and lead you down the wrong troubleshooting path? Yes, and I think they often do for those who don't understand what ping and tracert can actually tell us and when they're appropriate to use as connectivity diagnostic tools.

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael Hampton said, traceroute is your best friend. I am able to resolve and access the website just fine.

Are you able to at least ping it? If you can't ping it then you are probably blocked somehow. Is there a firewall running on that server? Can you use another IP to reach it?

[image: Pingplotter Traceroute]

Answer (score 1):

Hurricane's webhosting servers don't respond to traceroutes.  The same goes for a lot of intermediate routers of a lot of ISP's.  When submitting issues like this, always run ping as well as traceroute, and include both results.  Pathping, mtr, and WinMTR are also helpful tools.

Comment: One would have thought HE knew better than to block protocols commonly used to debug networking problems.

Comment: @kasperd HE probably does know better. Leaving ping open allows MTR to run, which is much better than traceroute. Also a TCP traceroute would show that a connection is being made (although it would usually fail at each hop before it)